# MCU controlled power-on sequence

Tags: microcontroller, avr, ldo

I would like to implement the power-on sequence of an IC. It has 3 different power supplies plus the clock, which has to be enabled *after* the power supplies. I am considering employing a ATTINY202 for the implementation, while the LDOs all belong to [TLV755P](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv755p.pdf?ts=1596022767545&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV755P) family. Clock has not yet been decided, but it will have an EN pin as well.

Now, my main concern is about the initialization (programming) phase of the MCU, on boot. When the MCU boots, until it has complete its own power up sequence and programs itself, the outputs are in High-Z state. That means that the EN pin of the LDOs are, and please correct me if I am wrong, floating. I could not explicitly locate in the datasheet what happens if the EN pin is unconnected, in chapter ***7.3.2 Enable (EN)***, so I am forced to assume that the behavior is undefined.

So, I am worried about that tiny fraction at the very beginning of powering up the PCB. I am thinking of tightening all EN inputs to the ground via a 10 kΩ pull-down resistor, to ensure that nothing is on the LDOs and clock output, but I don't like the idea of the constant current consumption.

Am I missing something? Is the power up time of the MCU insignificant to worry about? Also, could I use 100 kΩ / 1 MΩ pull down resistors safely, to further limit the current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pin is floating, so you must pull it down to ensure the regulator remains off. That is indicated in the (typical) 10nA EN input current shown in the datasheet.

There is no maximum listed so you're gambling with resistor value if you make it really high, but let's assume 1uA is safe. So you could use a ~1M resistor or 100K. And maybe parallel it with 100pF so that startup transients have less chance of turning it on (and don't make the PCB layout too too horrific like having the control line closely capacitively coupled to switched Vcc by running it 100mm on the wrong side of the board).

If the startup sequence is for something like a $5000 gate array (or if the cost of a field failure is otherwise quite high) you might want to  use **hardware** to ensure the startup rather than a microcontroller. There are dedicated chips for sequencing and supply supervisory functions that you can buy. Cost might be a bit higher but you don't need to maintain firmware etc., and they generally have guarantees as to operation under unpleasant conditions you may not have considered such as brownout input voltage.

Comment: I have considered the option of using an [LM3880](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3880.pdf?ts=1596044005166&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM3880), but it has control for 3 outputs. According to datasheet, the clock (oscillator) has to be enabled after the power supplies, and going with a supervisor which has 3 outputs is cost prohibitive compared to an ATTINY which is much less. The layout of the board will be very careful (multi-layer, MCU and LDOs will be close together). Another costly option is to cascade 2 LM3880. Based on the above, what do you think?

Comment: I recall some reasonably priced chips from Analog, I think, that can be daisy-chained.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on "[...] maybe parallel it with 100pF so that startup transients have less chance of turning it on"? I always thought that caps next to EN pins was for decoupling purpose, so in case of fluctuation that the chip does not switch off or becomes unstable. Also why 100pF? Is it so that it does increase rise time significantly when you want to set it to HIGH? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The higher the resistor is, the more likely it is that leakage or some stray capacitance will cause it to change state from the desired one. An infinitely high resistor means it's floating and will have unpredictable state. 100pF is going to be 10x or more the stray capacitance in any reasonable case, so it's sufficient. Since the pin is not being driven in this scenario, we could think of 1nF or 10nF too, but that cap gets discharged through the protection diodes if the power supply is shorted so a lower value may be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your LDO being off during startup, you will have to ensure its EN pin is low. That's the reason this thing has one of these.
Leaving it floating is nothing I would consider for a professional device.

If you are concerned by the current draw of the 10K pulldown, consider using a bigger one. 200k or more. Should be more than enough to pull EN consistently down.

Clock output is different, I don't see a reason of pulling a clock line down. Won't start oscillating on its own.

Comment: As I wrote in the original question, the clock has to be enabled after the power supplies are enabled. So, the oscillator should provide an output to the IC after all supplies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to have power up sequences with certain priorities given to certain voltages when this is required by the “device”. Say a 1.3V supply may need to be established before the 3.3V supply or 5V is applied, and so on, and then the clock etc. So, a voltage monitor IC may already be enough for you to be doing that, like it monitors the first priority voltage and when this reaches a minimum required threshold for this, it activates a Power Good (PG) pin you can use to then activate another (or other) power supply as required. There are also ones that monitor 2 voltages etc. so your ATTINY may be an overkill for doing this. Eventually the clock is also enabled by the correct voltage being applied, and if the “device” is held in RESET by a 100K pull-down anyway until ALL correct supplies are sequenced respectively then the clock isn’t really an issue if it’s powered up before the “device”. Consider if dedicated voltage monitors may already do this for you to ensure the power sequence you require. And yes, if 10K drains too much then why not 100K or 200K ?